# Flutter provider in initState

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm currently trying Provider as a state management solution, and I understand that it can't be used inside the initState function.

All examples that I've seen call a method inside a derived `ChangeNotifier` class upon user action (user clicks a button, for example), but what if I need to call a method when initialising my state?

Motivation:
Creating a screen which loads assets (async) and shows progress

An example for the `ChangeNotifier` class (can't call `add` from `initState`):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ProgressData extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _progress = 0;

  double get progress => _progress;

  void add(double dProgress) {
    _progress += dProgress;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can call such methods from the constructor of your `ChangeNotifier`:

```dart
class MyNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  MyNotifier() {
    someMethod();
  }

  void someMethod() {
    // TODO: do something
  }
}
```

Comment: If you call notifyListeners() inside the constructor and use the provider in build method, doesn't it cause infinite rebuild? or maybe MyNotifier will instantiate only once, like a singleton? appreciated if explained.

Comment: As I recall, the Class instance of ChangeNNotifier is created once and Provider avoids creating new copies unless absolutely required. It will not cause infinite re-render. Just tested :)

Answer (score 7):

Change your code to this

```dart
class ProgressData extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _progress = 0;

  double get progress => _progress;

  void add(double dProgress) async {
    // Loading Assets maybe async process with its network call, etc.
    _progress += dProgress;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ProgressData() {
    add();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In initState all the of(context) things don't work correctly, because the widget is not fully wired up with every thing in initState.
You can use this code:

```
Provider.of<ProgressData>(context, listen: false).add(progress);
```

Or this code:

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
 Provider.of<ProgressData>(context).add(progress)
});
```

Comment: To explain furthur, using `listen: false` is usually done when calling a method in the provider. But if you'd like to read data from the provider instead then keep it out.

Answer (score 1):

So an AssetLoader class which reports on its progress will look something like this, I guess:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ProgressData extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _progress = 0;

  ProgressData() {
    _loadFake();
  }

  Future<void> _loadFake() async {
    await _delayed(true, Duration(seconds: 1));
    _add(1.0);
    await _delayed(true, Duration(seconds: 2));
    _add(2.0);
    await _delayed(true, Duration(seconds: 3));
    _add(3.0);
  }

  // progress
  double get progress => _progress;

  // add
  void _add(double dProgress) {
    _progress += dProgress;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // _delayed
  Future<dynamic> _delayed(dynamic returnVal, Duration duration) {
    return Future.delayed(duration, () => returnVal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fateme said:

> the widget is not fully wired up with everything in initState

Also, you can use something like this in your `initState`

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      Provider.of<ProgressData>(context, listen: false).add(5);
    });
```

I think it's more standard!

Be aware that you should use the correct context! I mean the context of the Builder!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies with the fact that `context` does not exist yet in `initState` as extensively explained by the other answers. It doesn't exist because it hasn't yet been made a part of the widget tree.

#### Calling a method

If you're *not* assigning any state and *only* calling a method then `initState` would be the best place to get this done.

```dart
// The key here is the listen: false
Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).mymethod();
```

The code above is allowed by Flutter because it doesn't have to listen for anything. In short, it's a one off. Use it where you only want to do something instead of read/listen to something.

#### Listening to changes

Alternatively, if you need to listen to changes from Provider then the use of `didChangeDependencies` would be the best place to do so as `context` would exist here as in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html).

> This method is also called immediately after initState.

```dart
int? myState;

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  // No listen: false
  myState = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).data;
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

If you've never used `didChangeDependencies` before, what it does is get called whenever `updateShouldNotify()` returns true. This in turn lets any widgets that requested an inherited widget in `build()` respond as needed.

I'd usually use this method in a `FutureBuilder` to prevent reloading data when data already exists in Provider after switching screens. This way I can just check Provider for `myState` and skip the preloader (if any) entirely.

Hope this helps.